# How to correctly use a type guard when looping through nested arrays?

Tags: arrays, string, typescript, nested, typeguards

While looping through an array, I need to differentiate between two possible types of its elements:

- either each element is a string, or
- each element is an array of strings.

```
function _addDataAtIndex(
    totalData: Array<string | string[]>,
    dataToAdd: Array<Array<string | string[]>>,
    addIndex: number,
) {
    dataToAdd.forEach((dataArr) => {
        if (dataArr.every((x) => typeof x === 'string')) {
            // each value is a string - insert the entire array
            totalData.splice(addIndex, 0, dataArr);
        } else {
            totalData.splice(addIndex, 0, dataArr[0]);
        }
    });
}
```

However, TypeScript doesn't seem able to infer the type of the nested array even with seemingly robust type guards. I still need the type guard to ensure I'm on the right branch, but then I have to cast the array, `dataArr as string[]`, to tell TypeScript there's not a problem. this is redundant and brittle, and I feel like there has to be a way to do this with a cleaner type guard.

I've searched through many other questions, but the answers I've found there, such as custom type guard functions, don't work either, see [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAfQIYBN0BFVVQQSgEkx0BTADwAoAoRexKOPAGxzwC5F8AnH1AJ4AeAM5QeMMAHNEAH0RiJ0gNoBdAHwAaOg3S5UAFTj5MXXv2HnBo8ZJnzFdteq076GdCXIUuYEAFsAIzIebQBKRABvN0Q9PCMTdAA6YDgeAFFUCAALKio4gj4IgF51KJiGRBhgRHz9cySyADcQgTyKErKoAQAHMjgaikRikcQAckdpMbCI6Mr5hiZWdlQkkR6WGAgyKg8vSk1EAAZDgvMwgG4KhgBfRDIWETJyhYWl1DZ9NY2tnb3SA7HU71PjKI6qS7Xeg3GI3SEwmgQBBiKoiKwCADywAAyrZpCJhrVUDwpGY%20NZJvYFHipM5OohiVJGi0eG0hqVGL1%20oNhqMJjTplcaKBILAECgPCtCPsKAB1GBQbIAcRAxPQADFwBBaJV3p9ONxycJKXJqUpaRptJUCglTIaLEJ0TZzabKc5XJV-t5fAFgqEaLMYjbjJgUmlMjk8mcisMynNXtVajA0UasbjzSI6nhzoHXvM9StvpttrtMDLDidYiCeJC83cHk8XnnFswPoX1sW-mWARQK8Ds6DwbXXjDKnCrjcgA).

Is there a clean way to discriminate between `string | string[]` without changing the entire structure? all I can think of is to turn the inner values into objects of some custom union interface, and that's way too messy for this use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript can't understand your `.every` call as a type guard. You can write your own [type guard/predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) for this, although that's not necessary. The typing for `.every` has two overloads, one that is an actual predicate:

```
    /**
     * Determines whether all the members of an array satisfy the specified test.
     * @param predicate A function that accepts up to three arguments. The every method calls
     * the predicate function for each element in the array until the predicate returns a value
     * which is coercible to the Boolean value false, or until the end of the array.
     * @param thisArg An object to which the this keyword can refer in the predicate function.
     * If thisArg is omitted, undefined is used as the this value.
     */
    every<S extends T>(predicate: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): this is S[];

    /**
     * Determines whether all the members of an array satisfy the specified test.
     * @param predicate A function that accepts up to three arguments. The every method calls
     * the predicate function for each element in the array until the predicate returns a value
     * which is coercible to the Boolean value false, or until the end of the array.
     * @param thisArg An object to which the this keyword can refer in the predicate function.
     * If thisArg is omitted, undefined is used as the this value.
     */
    every(predicate: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): boolean;
```

To use the type guard overload version, the predicate you pass to `.every` needs to be a type guard itself. You can simply add a return type to your array function that marks it as a type guard:

```
function _addDataAtIndex(
    totalData: Array<string | string[]>,
    dataToAdd: Array<Array<string | string[]>>,
    addIndex: number,
) {
    dataToAdd.forEach((dataArr) => {
        // Note the `: x is string` here
        if (dataArr.every((x): x is string => typeof x === 'string')) {
            // each value is a string - insert the entire array
            totalData.splice(addIndex, 0, dataArr);
        } else {
            totalData.splice(addIndex, 0, dataArr[0]);
        }
    });
}
```

Now it uses the type guard-version of `.every` which makes TypeScript realize `dataArr` is a `string[]` within that branch of the if-statement.

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for - good explanation, too. thank you!